# How to stop a task in Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have written a batch job using spring batch and I executed it as task in spring cloud data flow admin, My problem is when I launch the task, It cannot be canceled or paused, It runs at once and the status gets completed:
[image: while launcing],
[image: after completation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you're running a batch-job that completes rapidly.

Perhaps you could have a sample to mimic the behavior of a long-running batch-job (eg: a job that runs for 5mins or more); with that type of an application, once after the launch, you'd be able to switch to the "Jobs" tab to select the option "Stop the job" to stop the currently running batch-job.

Here's the visual toggle for reference:

[image: Toggle to select "Stop the job" option for each batch-job]

Comment: Thank you, so It can't be stopped in less than 5 mins?

Comment: It is not about the time really. The first launch takes a few extra seconds depending on the app-size, because SCDF downloads the app and then it deploys it on the targeted platform. When you launch it for the 1st time, you may see the "spinner" in UI blocking any operation, which is why you cannot get to the "Jobs" page.

Comment: Any subsequent launch of the same batch-job, of course, is quick because your app operation is faster perhaps. After when you click the launch, and then navigate to "Jobs" tab, the app probably completes its operation may be. That's why I suggested trying a long-running batch-job to observe the behavior. Again, there's no hard time-limit as to when you can stop a batch-job.